# Get all link from a html

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

In PHP how can I get all link from a HTML document.

For example: `<a href="www.blabla.com">To Bla</a>`

In php I need the link: www.blabla.com.

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: With <strike>regex</strike> a HTML parser. [PhpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) looks nice.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Maybe this will help: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/php/parse-links/

Summary:

```
<?php

// Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header.

$url = "http://www.example.net/somepage.html";
$input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
$regexp = "<a\s[^>]*href=(\"??)([^\" >]*?)\\1[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>";
if(preg_match_all("/$regexp/siU", $input, $matches)) {
    // $matches[2] = array of link addresses
    // $matches[3] = array of link text - including HTML code
}

?>
```

Comment: This might be good for checking other pages, but how can you check the page the php is executing from, because $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] doesn't seem to work...